# How can I add something from the Java recursion problem on finding paths?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm making a Java program where it counts the number of paths. I want it to only go up (north) and right (east). I also want it to output the paths taken. Is there something I can do?

```
import java.io.*;

public class PathsRecursion {
    public static int countPaths(int n, int e) {
        int dp[][] = new int[n + 1][e + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            dp[i][0] = 1;

        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= e; i++) {
            dp[0][i] = 1;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= e; j++) {
            dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j] + dp[i][j - 1];
        }
        return dp[n][e];
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 1, e = 3;
        System.out.println("Number of Paths: " + countPaths(n, e));
    }
}
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely different languages that only share "Java" in their names, but that's it.

Comment: Why is this not working? What is the expected output, and what is the output you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You added an extra row and column to you dp array. It needs to be a `n` by `e` array, not `n + 1` by `e + 1` array.

```
import java.io.*;

public class PathsRecursion {
    public static int countPaths(int n, int e) {
        int dp[][] = new int[n][e];
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            dp[i][0] = 1;

        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= e; i++) {
            dp[0][i] = 1;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= e; j++) {
            dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j] + dp[i][j - 1];
        }
        return dp[n - 1][e - 1];
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 1, e = 3;
        System.out.println("Number of Paths: " + countPaths(n, e));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: At the end, you have to access `dp[n - 1][e - 1];` instead of `return dp[n][e];` because of the 0-indexing.